# SQL - check for duplicate names/nicknames

Tags: sql

I have a query that gives me duplicate names in my table.  But, I need to add the checking of nicknames.  I've tried many variations but am still stumped.  The following query takes oave 12 minutes to run so I canceled it.

```
WITH TEAM2 as
(
      SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName order by LastName, FirstName,ID DESC) RN
      FROM dbo.vw_Users_Details
      WHERE Lastname <> '' 
      AND Firstname <> ''
      AND Not_Dupe_Flag <> 1 
)

SELECT a.ID, a.LastName, a.FirstName
FROM TEAM2 a
where exists (select 1
              from TEAM2 b 
              where (b.FirstName = a.FirstName 
              and b.LastName = a.LastName 
              and b.RN > 1)
              OR
              (b.LastName = a.LastName
              AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pdNicknames AS c WHERE c.NAME = a.firstname AND c.variation = b.firstname) 
              and b.RN > 1)
              )
order by a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.id
```

Comment: What's `ID`?  `userId` or `nameId`?  And what is the end goal?  If it's `userId` you will of course have duplicates, and they _cannot_ be gotten rid of ("Sorry Mr. Smith, you're now Gref Azak"); if it's `nameId`, we may want to tweak the design... What does your table layout look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening to my replies.  They're not showing up anymore.  
Anyway, I don't understand the questions. This is pretty straight forward.  I need to list the duplicate names but I need to account for possible nicknames.

Comment: Using a name that is _commonly_ a nick-name (for some other name) doesn't make two names a duplicate (or an indicator of the same person).  Again, what is your table layout?  There's multiple possible solutions, but they depend on how your data is laid out; among other things, I'm wary of `Not_Dupe_Flag`.  And what are you attempting to accomplish?  If you're trying to query the US census data for similarily named people, I'd imagine that'd take several days... Oh, nicknames (in your example query) are only checked if there are duplicate regular names, probably not what you want.

Comment: I have a table that has an identity column (ID), firstname, lastname, company name, and a not_dupe_flag that tells me that this record has alreeady been checked. It's an ongoing problem to check this table for dupes.  Rows are entered via the internet.  If someone adds a a row as Bob Adams and later adds it again as Robert Adams,  I want to see those rows as possible duplicates.

Comment: Your `Not_Dupe_Flag` is (potentially) useless, depending on use and table maintenece - you seem to have the boolean backwards.  Does `ID` refer to a _person_, or is it supposed to refer to a _name_?  If it refers to a _person_, how do you know that 'duplicate' names don't refer to _different_ people (and is that important)?  If it is supposed to refer to _name_, why are you so sure that a 'nickname' version isn't a valid name on it's own - couldn't somebody be named just 'Bob Greggs', and not have 'Bob' be short for 'Robert'?

Comment: I understand the shortcoming of the not_dupe_flag.  Skip that. ID refers to a person. I don't care if Bob is his given name.  If it's a possible duplicate, I want to see it.

Comment: Will each person (the `ID` column) have multiple entries, or is `ID` garuanteed to be unique?

Comment: Id is an identity column.  It is unique for each person.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause.

For example:

```
select b.Branches_ShortName
from kplus..Folders f
inner join kplus..Portfolios p on p.Portfolios_Id = f.Portfolios_Id
inner join kplus..Branches b on b.Branches_Id = p.Branches_Id
group by Branches_ShortName
having count(Branches_ShortName) > 1
```

This will provide only the Branches that have more than 1 Folder :)

Comment: there is additional duplicate check in OP's code: take a look at usage of table pdNicknames.

Comment: ID   Last Name   First Name   Company Name                            
212    Adams      Robert       xyz                           
345    Adams      Robert       bnbnbn
4102   Adams      Bob          unknown

Comment: Come on you guys.  Think.  This gets complicated.  I can get duplicates for Robert Adams. But If I have a Robert and a Bob, I need to show them as possible dupes.

Comment: don't you just need to know the list of people that are duplicates?

Comment: @user990016 then, by applying a group by + having count() in your query you can have what you want

Comment: No, Group By clobbers the theaory of substituting a firstname.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're attempting to find all *users* who share the same name/nickname.
I believe the following should work;

```
SELECT a.ID, a.LastName, a.FirstName
FROM dbo.vw_Users_Details as a
WHERE a.LastName <> ''
AND a.FirstName <> ''
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM dbo.vw_Users_Details as b
            LEFT JOIN pdNicknames as c
            ON (c.name = b.FirstName 
                AND c.variation = a.FirstName)
            OR (c.name = a.FirstName 
                AND c.variation = b.FirstName)
            WHERE b.ID <> a.ID
            AND b.LastName = a.LastName
            AND (b.FirstName = a.FirstName
                 OR (c.name IS NOT NULL OR c.variation IS NOT NULL)
                )
            )
```

I make no garuantees about the execution performance of this statement, as you haven't provided enough information for us to know.  However, it's likely to be better, given you won't need the OLAP; I do recommend indicies on the various names and `variation`, of course.  I left off `Not_Dupe_Flag` because I'm a little confused by it's use (because you seem to be using '1' as 'false', which is *opposite* to how most comparisons are setup); at minimum, never include 'Not' as part of a boolean variable name - it makes reasoning about it difficult (use `Unique_Name` or `Duplicated_Name`, either of which is immediately understandable).

---

EDIT:

If you need to restrict your selection, I recommend encapsulating the query in a view (including the `ROW_NUMBER()` function), and query the view.  Alternatively, if your RDBMS supports it, wrap the query in a CTE.  Multiple nested `FROM` clauses are like multiple nested `if` statements - confusing.  Being able to logically seperate parts of the query with a view or CTE goes a long way to retaining sanity.

Comment: SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, Name
FROM (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.ID DESC)) AS ROWNUM, a.ID, a.LastName, a.FirstName
FROM dbo.vw_Users_Details as a
WHERE a.LastName <> ''
AND a.FirstName <> ''
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM dbo.vw_Users_Details as b
 LEFT JOIN pdNicknames as c
 ON c.name = a.FirstName
 and c.variation = b.FirstName
WHERE b.ID <> a.ID AND b.LastName = a.LastName
AND (b.FirstName = a.FirstName
OR (c.name IS NOT NULL AND c.name = a.FirstName
AND c.variation IS NOT NULL AND c.variation = b.FirstName))))
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 and 100

Comment: @user990016 - Sorry, but your query isn't going to work; without both checks, you're going to be dropping results from one direction (unless you've got both directions in that `pdNicknames` table, which you shouldn't).  And if you're using a nested `FROM`, you need to alias the resulting table (put ` AS A ` between that last parenthesis and the final `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The pdNicknames table does indeed have Bob-Robert and Robert-Bob which makes it work.

Comment: @user990016 - That's just asking for trouble.  I garuantee you that eventually something is going to be out-of-sync.  You're also storing either 2n or n! factorial combinations, instead of n (size of the problem may be mitigated by size of input source).  You can (and probably should) generate a view/MQT which _does_ have both/all directions, but this shouldn't be done as part of your base table.